# How to drag functionlity work with in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery drag and drop functionality when I drag it moves all over the browser. I need to fix some particular height and width drag works only the particular fixed size. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a container `<div>` to call the jQuery `draggable` function on. Also see this [jQuery Ui example](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

```js
$(".example").draggable({
  containment: ".box"
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.example {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="example">Drag me</div>
</div>
```